# Join tables and display city.name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Having issues joining two tables and displaying the other value, tables are setup and models are loaded and starts with a capital letter.

What i want is to match jobs.city_id and cities.id and display cities.city_name

Jobs_model.php

```
public function get_city(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('cities');
$this->db->join('jobs', 'cities.city_name = jobs.city_id');
$this->db->where('jobs.city_id = cities.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
}
```

Controller.php

```
$data['city_name'] = $this->jobs_model->get_city();
```

View.php

```
<?php echo $city_name['city_name'];?>
```

SQL

```
CITIES
id
city_name

JOBS
id
city_id
```

update. sql and typo

Comment: Show tables city and jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You also have not returned any thing in model function

If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer.

This function example below only will return one row at a time you may need to use result_array(); read this link below how to generate results https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

```
public function get_city(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('cities');
    $this->db->join('jobs', 'jobs.city_id = cities.id', 'LEFT');
    //$this->db->where('jobs.city_id = cities.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // Note only returns one row
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

And On Controller

```
$info = $this->jobs_model->get_city();

$data['city_name'] = $info['city_name'];
```

---

#### Multiple Results

```
public function get_city(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('cities');
    $this->db->join('jobs', 'jobs.city_id = cities.id', 'LEFT');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And on controller

```
$data['cities'] = $this->jobs_model->get_city();
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($cities as $city) {?>
    <?php echo $city['city_name'];?>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a simple SQL for reference - 

`select cities.name from cities, jobs where jobs.city_id = cities.id`

Answer (score 0):

Change your **Model** to

```
public function get_city(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('cities');
$this->db->join('jobs', 'cities.city_id= jobs.city_id');
$this->db->where('jobs.city_id = cities.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
join('jobs', 'cities.id = jobs.city_id');
```

I think that's the issue.

Comment: Solved the get issue but im not getting cities.name still.

Comment: It's cities.city_name and not cities.name according to your schema.

Comment: typo here in stack. Its not throwing any errors but i'm not getting any data in in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing wrong field in join query

```
public function get_city(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('cities');
$this->db->join('jobs', 'cities.id = jobs.city_id'); //<---id instead of city_name
//$this->db->where('jobs.city_id = cities.id'); // remove  where
$query = $this->db->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$this->db->join('jobs', 'cities.city_id = jobs.city_id');
```

instead of this

```
$this->db->join('jobs', 'cities.city_name = jobs.city_id');
```